# Nextjs _app.js shared layout how to run server side ( Closed )

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a simple nextjs application

=> pages/_app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Provider store={store}><SiteLayout><Component {...pageProps} /></SiteLayout></Provider>
}
```

=> layouts/SiteLayout.js : In here, I make a request to api and draw the menu.

```
export default function SiteLayout({ children }) {
    const dispath = useDispatch()
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("testlink", {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
            method: 'POST',
            body: "client=web"
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => dispath(addFeed(data)))
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <Menu />
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
```

I know it is not server-side rendered and my problem is that I want to do it server-side because the menu tree can’t show in the source code. I need to request one time and draw a scaffold of the application in SiteLayout shared component.  Did anyone solve or face that?

---

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async function (context) {
    const data = await fetch("testlik", {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        method: 'POST',
        body: "client=web"
    }).then(response => response.json())
    return {
        pageProps:{
            menu: data?.data?.menu ?? null
        }
    }
}
```

getInitialProps is fixed my issue

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve but  next.13 experimental app directory feature:might be what you need:  https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/app-directory-roadmap

Comment: When I check the view page source the <Menu /> component can't appear because it's running client side. If I move the <Menu/> component to index.js from the <SiteLayout /> component and use getServerSideProps then the <Menu /> appears in the view page source because it's a server-side behavior. But this is not my want to do because If I start like that I have to add the <Menu /> component on every page. I simply create a header, content, and footer scaffold in the <SiteLayout /> component. But the problem is the <Menu /> is dynamic and there is no function to handle it like getServerSideProps.